# Mars is dark, surrounding is bright, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, mars

I just got a Celestron 8 and I'm a complete rookie: set up scope early so it would acclimate to the temperature. No difficulty locating Mars, but I see a dark planet with its circumference slightly illuminated and the night sky around it is bright? (scope in good dark location and nice dark sky) No amount of fine tuning makes a difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like something is very wrong.  Perhaps what you think is "mars" is the shadow of the secondary mirror and you are very out of focus.  I suggest you "practice" during the day.  Mars should appear as a very small disc perhaps with some surface features visible (but Mars is small and hard!)

Comment: Can you take an image so we can see what you are seeing. As James pointed out, there must be something wrong with the setup you have.

Comment: See answers to [Black dot visible when looking into the telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37189/7982) and [Mirror telescope: blocked sight](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19826/7982) and [Struggling to use my new telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27043/7982) and [Astromaster Celestron 130 EQ](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39251/7982) The middle two have photos for comparison, because they are Newtonian telescopes you can also see the secondary mirror's spider mount in the shadows.

Comment: thanks very much, will do bit of daytime practice

Comment: Great, but please be careful to avoid pointing anywhere near the Sun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are very out of focus. Dial the focuser all the way out towards you. The little knob on the right.

Comment: thanks+++, that worked , saw mars tonite.

Comment: @kilroryOConnor That's great news, congratulations! Btw you can consider clicking the "accept" check mark next to the answer This will give you a small reputation (points) bump and one to this answer's author as well, and also indicate to future readers that this question has been answered.

Comment: Excellent. Welcome to astronomy and clear skies!